# Elasticsearch - match all children items in a nested array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I've documents like these - 
Doc1:

```
{
    "attr1": "attrVal1",
    "nestedAttr": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "type": "Type1",
           "output": "PASS"
        },
        {
           "id": 2,
           "type": "Type2",
           "output": "FAIL"
        },
        {
           "id": 3,
           "type": "Type1",
           "output": "PASS"
        }
    ]

}
```

Doc2:

```
{
    "attr1": "attrVal1",
    "nestedAttr": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "type": "Type2",
           "output": "PASS"
        },
        {
           "id": 2,
           "type": "Type1",
           "output": "FAIL"
        },
        {
           "id": 3,
           "type": "Type1",
           "output": "PASS"
        }
    ]

}
```

nestedAttr is of nested mapping. I want to search of all **attr1**s which have "type": "Type1" and "output": "PASS". I don't care about the output of Type2 but if any of the Type1 has FAIL in a document, it should be ignored. 
So in above example, Doc1 will be returned for the query and Doc2 will not be returned.

I tried queries with permutation and combination of must and must_not but all are just searching for at least one match among the nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your mapping for the nested object/collection is propery set up, you can use the [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

**Prepare: Delete the Index**

```
DELETE test_nested
```

**Prepare: Set the Nested-Mapping**

```
PUT test_nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "attr1": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "nestedAttr": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "output": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Prepare: Create doc #1**

```
POST test_nested/_doc/1
{
  "attr1": "attrVal1",
  "nestedAttr": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "Type1",
      "output": "PASS"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "Type2",
      "output": "FAIL"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "Type3",
      "output": "PASS"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Prepare: Create doc #2**

```
POST test_nested/_doc/2
{
  "attr1": "attrVal1",
  "nestedAttr": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "Type2",
      "output": "PASS"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "Type1",
      "output": "FAIL"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "Type3",
      "output": "FAIL"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search: (nestedAttr.type:Type1 AND nestedAttr.output:PASS)**

```
POST /test_nested/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nestedAttr",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "nestedAttr.type": "Type1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "nestedAttr.output": "PASS"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result: count(nestedAttr.type:Type1 AND nestedAttr.output:PASS) = 1**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.7227666,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_nested",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.7227666,
        "_source" : {
          "attr1" : "attrVal1",
          "nestedAttr" : [
            {
              "id" : 1,
              "type" : "Type1",
              "output" : "PASS"
            },
            {
              "id" : 2,
              "type" : "Type2",
              "output" : "FAIL"
            },
            {
              "id" : 3,
              "type" : "Type3",
              "output" : "PASS"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the query I tried. It returns the parent document which has even on entry of {"type": "Type1", "output": "PASS"}. So, the above query will return Doc1 and Doc2 as well.

Comment: because your example docs are buggy. both docs are matching because they contain '{"id": 3,"type": "Type1", "output": "PASS"}' at nestedAttr[2] (last position). I've edited my answer with a working example - feel free to adopt the solution.

Comment: Is there any way to do this if it's not type nested?

Comment: @claudekennilol, I have the same requirement. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @HishamMubarak Nope, we made a new table and migrated the data, if you do it all in elasticsearch it's a very quick process

Comment: Sorry mates, but there is really no other way as changing the mapping  and reindexing

Comment: @claudekennilol, Yep, I couldn't get any workaround for it either. Had to change my data type from doc to nested and reindex data, all works great now.